# Git fatal: index-pack failed

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

I tried cloning a git repository to my local folder and I get this error.
I used TortoiseGIT version 1.8.5 (64 bit)

```
git.exe clone  --recursive    --progress -v  --depth 1000000 "https://github.com/myrep/dotnet.git" "C:\Projects\PFM\dn1\dotnet"

Cloning into 'C:\Projects\PFM\dn1\dotnet'...
POST git-upload-pack (221 bytes)
POST git-upload-pack (230 bytes)
remote: Counting objects: 10572, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3317/3317), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (10572/10572), 60.57 MiB | 843 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7373/7373), done.
remote: Total 10572 (delta 7373), reused 10047 (delta 6848)
fatal: index-pack failed


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (82009 ms @ 24-09-2013 21:28:10)
```

Please help me to resolve this.

**Update:** Everything was working fine in India, i recently moved to UK and when i tried here it is not working :) I am wondering about this. Is there any server configuration problem? If i do the same thing in remote machine in India, it works fine. :) I have no idea on it

Comment: Do you have `transfer.fsckObjects` set?  You can use `git config --get transfer.fsckObjects` to find out.

Comment: @jszakmeister how do i check? In git or in TortoiseGit tool?

Comment: I'd use the git command line and run the command I gave above: `git config --get transfer.fsckObjects`.

Comment: @jszakmeister, I opened GIT command line tool and went to my folder like `cd projects/PFM` and run the command you gave. After that i tried cloning, still I get same error

Comment: @jszakmeister, everything was working fine in India, i recently moved to UK and when i tried here it is not working :) I am wondering about this. Is there any server configuration problem? If i do the same thing in remote machine in India, it works fine. :) I have no idea on it

Comment: It wasn't meant to enable you to clone.  It was meant to see if you have `transfer.fsckObjects` set.  What was the output?  Empty?  It may be you have a poor connection.  Is there anything else to error message?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when git ran out of memory.

Freeing up some memory (in this case: letting a compile job finish) and trying again worked for me.

Maybe your UK machine has less free memory?